# jQuery Chain this with selector

Tags: jquery, this, chaining, chain

Is it possible to chain 'this' with other selectors

i.e

```
var testvar =jQuery(this.label.text()).val();
```

Comment: add more code to understanding

Comment: Can you show us your code and explain what you are try to do.

Comment: `$(this).text('foo').width(200).show();`

Comment: what are you trying to do, show more code

Answer (score 1):

jQuery selector accepts a string parameter and based on that it return a jQuery object or Array with jQuery Objects.

Assuming that you are trying to find an Element and the Element Selector match is stored to another Element than you can do something like this

```
$("a.button").click(function(){
    var element = $($(this).data("elementID"));
});
```

Where the anchor looks something like this :

```
<a href="#" data-elementID="#firstElement">Find</a>
```

and the target element is :

```
<div id="firstElement"></div>
```

From that case you can easily reference another Element from another One.